# Screenshot into AIR application

Tags: air

Is there away to copy a screenshot directly into an Adobe Air (2) application? 
Kinda like this: User presses the "print screen" button and the screenshot shows up in the app.

Also I'ld like to know if pasting via keyboard or right-click work for that?

I'm new too AIR.
Best, John

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.
But no, not directly from Air, unless you wish to capture parts of your own AIR UI (which should be no problem as these are within the scope of the AIR Application)

To capture the whole screen you would need to use an ANE (Adobe Native Extension) which can be written
both for iOS and Android devices and used from within AIR via an API.

Introduction to ANE Development:http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/air_extensions.pdf

The following post discusses on the way by which an Air ANE can capture a screenshot (which is technical and relevant for developing such an ANE for Android)

[How Native Extension take screenshot on Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164321/how-native-extension-take-screenshot-on-android-device)

Other then this you might try a workaround, that is, instructing the user to capture using his own device's capture combination, then simply ask them to select the file from the Gallery, if indeed this is your intention...?